# React: Understanding the use of Error Boundaries

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I have some questions regarding catching Errors in React 16.

Currently, we deal with ChunkLoadErrors when we create new releases for our application. So I thought of implementing an Error Boundary that wraps our whole application. Now a couple of questions arose:

It seems that those Errors aren't really "caught" as a `try / catch` statement would do. Meaning, if an Error would arise, it still gets thrown to the Browser, therefore in development mode, the application actually breaks and you can't see the fallback UI. Does that mean services like Sentry will also still get notified about those errors, even though they are handled?

Second: Is it maybe bad practice to wrap the whole application in an Error Boundary and filter out specific errors? If so, is there a better solution? I'm thinking of doing the following inside my Error Boundary (TS):

```
static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
if (error.name === "ChunkLoadError") {
    // Catching ChunkLoadError
    return { hasError: true, theError: error };
}
throw error;
}
```

Lastly, is there anything I should be aware of in my use-case that I might forget?

I appreciate all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

> Error Boundary that wraps our whole application

Frankly speaking it is not a good idea. It is intended for component level errors to catch so that other components can run smoothly. Let's say you have 1000 products and if there is an issue with 99th product only then it should be handled within and others should not get impacted.

> if an Error would arise, it still gets thrown to the Browser, therefore in development mode, the application actually breaks and you can't see the fallback UI.

The error trace has the highest priority in development mode **but** if you have implemented the ***Error boundary*** to component and then error happens then you can see error trace in the browser. Yet you can see a **`X`** at top right to remove the trace block to see the fallback UI.

[You can get more info here.](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/error-handling-using-error-boundaries-in-react-e7c8f27d778e)

Comment: So how would you propose to handle a situation like that? We want to handle that specific error application-wide but ignore all others...